# What is the equivalent of Page.Focus in .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, focus

I have been programming in webforms and recently started learning .NET core .Is there any equivalent of Page.Focus or Focus of webforms in .NET Core . I searched in the internet and found some older articles of MVC where they used javascript ,was wondering if there is any solution without javascript.I have a contact us form that is at the bottom and needs to be scrolled down ,however after submit the page loads again and i am taken to the top of the page ,i need to keep the focus on submit button.

Comment: There is no equivalent because MVC and Razor pages execute on the server only and then only produce a bare HTML output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been programming in webforms and recently started learning .NET core .Is there any equivalent of Page.Focus or Focus of webforms in .NET Core.

Currently, we can not create WebForm project with using WebForm server controls directly in ASP.NET Core. And as poke mentioned in comment, there is no equivalent project template that you can migrate from ASP.NET WebForm.

But you can try [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) that make coding page-focused scenarios easier, and you can define different handler methods in `.cshtml.cs` to handle different logic, which would be similar as you did in ASP.NET WebForm.

> I have a contact us form that is at the bottom and needs to be scrolled down ,however after submit the page loads again and i am taken to the top of the page ,i need to keep the focus on submit button.

You can try following approaches:

**Approach 1**: set `autofocus` for your input, which would help focus that control automatically when the page is loaded.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" autofocus />
```

**Approach 2**:  store scroll position in localStorage, then dynamically scroll the window to a particular place based on the stored data while page loads.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myfunc();" />
```

JS code

```
<script>
    function myfunc() {
        localStorage.setItem("scrollY", window.scrollY);
    }

    $(function () {
        var y = localStorage.getItem("scrollY");

        if (y != "" && y != null) {
            window.scroll(0, y);
        }
    })
</script>
```

Test Result

[image]